# Select the text in my css class

Tags: css, button, text, hover, skew

I have a button in my website that I animated when I hover over it.
I skew the button from right to left when a person hovers over the button.
The text inside the button skews with the button which I dont want.
I want the text to remain normal without any skewing while I hover the button.
I tried javascript but did not succeed.
My code so far:

```css
.btnredskewed
{
    font-family: 'cabinbold';
 border: #f94f4f solid 3px; 
 border-radius: 6px;
 background-color: #f94f4f; 
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s;
 
 -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.btnredskewed:hover
{
    font-family: 'cabinbold';
 border: #9cbce4 solid 3px; 
 border-radius: 6px;
 background-color: #9cbce4; 
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  
 -ms-transform: skewX(20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.unskewtext
{
 -ms-transform: skewX(20deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg); /* Safari */
 transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.unskewtext:hover
{
 -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* Safari */
 transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#mogelijkheden"><button type="button" class="btnredskewed margintopsmall"><div class="unskewtext">bekijk de mogelijkheden</div></button></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your CSS like this (you need to make the skew in the other direction with **the same speed**, like that it seems not moving)  :

```css
.btnredskewed {
  font-family: 'cabinbold';
  border: #f94f4f solid 3px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #f94f4f;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.btnredskewed:hover {
  font-family: 'cabinbold';
  border: #9cbce4 solid 3px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #9cbce4;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.unskewtext {
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btnredskewed:hover .unskewtext {
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#mogelijkheden"><button type="button" class="btnredskewed margintopsmall"><div class="unskewtext">bekijk de mogelijkheden</div></button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have added this css. For text remain normal you give `transform` effect on hover and give `transition` in normal text class `.unskewtext`.

```
.btnredskewed:hover .unskewtext {
   -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg); 
   -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); 
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
 }
.unskewtext
{ 
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s;  
 transition: 0.2s;  
}
```

```css
.btnredskewed
{
  font-family: 'cabinbold';
  border: #f94f4f solid 3px; 
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #f94f4f; 
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s; 
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.btnredskewed:hover
{
  font-family: 'cabinbold';
  border: #9cbce4 solid 3px; 
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #9cbce4; 
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.unskewtext
{
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s; 
  transition: 0.2s; 
}

.unskewtext:hover
{
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
.btnredskewed:hover .unskewtext {
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg); 
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); 
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#mogelijkheden"><button type="button" class="btnredskewed margintopsmall"><div class="unskewtext">bekijk de mogelijkheden</div></button></a>
```

Comment: you have almost the same result as in the question, check it .. he doesn't want the text to skew

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Please see carefully text doesn't skew on hover.

Comment: am not talking about the final state, look at the transition ... it's skewing before getting back to normal state ... this is what we need to avoid

Comment: he said : "I want the text to remain normal without **any** skewing while I hover the button"

Comment: I forgot to put transition in normal text otherwise my answer is correct.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Please update your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @FluffyKitten , I have explained my code. sorry for inconvenience but don't know why someone give downvote to my answer.

Comment: I don't know, it wasn't me. But the comments suggest that the answer you have before editing didn't address the issue.